Assign icc color profile to cmyk image using little cms please provide example
how do i apply icc color profile to the cmyk data
profileData,profileLength this contains the icc color profile data
Ihave tried applying using littlecms
void applyICCProfileToCMYK(cv::Mat& cmykImage, const void* profileData, uint32 profileLength) {
    try {
        // Open the input ICC profile from memory
        cmsHPROFILE hInProfile = cmsOpenProfileFromMem(profileData, profileLength);
        if (!hInProfile) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open input ICC profile.");
        }

        // For CMYK, we can use the same profile for input and output if no specific output profile is provided
        cmsHPROFILE hOutProfile = cmsOpenProfileFromMem(profileData, profileLength);
        if (!hOutProfile) {
            cmsCloseProfile(hInProfile);
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open output ICC profile.");
        }

        // Define color space formats
        cmsUInt32Number cmykFormat = TYPE_CMYK_8; // Assuming 8-bit CMYK input

        // Create a color transformation from CMYK to CMYK
        cmsHTRANSFORM hTransform = cmsCreateTransform(hInProfile, cmykFormat, hOutProfile, cmykFormat, INTENT_PERCEPTUAL, 0);
        if (!hTransform) {
            cmsCloseProfile(hInProfile);
            cmsCloseProfile(hOutProfile);
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create color transform.");
        }

        // Perform the color conversion
        cmsDoTransform(hTransform, cmykImage.data, cmykImage.data, cmykImage.total() * cmykImage.channels());

        // Clean up
        cmsDeleteTransform(hTransform);
        cmsCloseProfile(hInProfile);
        cmsCloseProfile(hOutProfile);

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}


but i am not getting the correct result.

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please share a minimal reproducible example! This includes a sample input image, your current output and a sketch of the expected output.
